# Setting relative path for image elements in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-path

Is there a way to set relative path for image elements (like a company logo) in ArcMap maps?

The classic "Store relative path" option in the Map Properties doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had thought that the normal store relative path covered images.  However, I think this may be what you are after.

Right click your image and go to properties, and then tick the save image as part of document (see below). This should then stop it losing the path and keep the image with the .mxd

[image: Save image as part of doucment]